# Log message/error at design-time in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have had a problem with a custom component I am writing. The issue seems to be a resource not loading properly (not sure why) at design-time.

To track it down I'd like to put in some debug-code that will execute at design-time, and give output in form of some messages.

Is there a log or something similar that can be written to at design-time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a really nice trick you can use to add debug statements in IntelliJ without actually changing the code.  The answer is to use non-suspending breakpoints.

Add a breakpoint at the necessary point in the code, then right click on it.  De-select "Suspend", and then put whatever you want in the "Log evaluated expression" - this will give you access to the fields of the instance.

Run your app in debug mode, and you'll get debugging info in the console without having to manually examine everything.

[image]

Comment: That is a cool trick, and I will definitely use it, but I'm trying to figure out something I can do at design-time. I.e. while using the GUI editor.

Comment: Are you getting a stack trace? Or am I still on the wrong track here?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to see what's going on at design-time (not runtime). I've just found that I can use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog to show some messages - which has helped me figure out that there seems to be a problem loading a resource at design-time (but which does load okay at runtime).

Comment: Ah, you're talking about when you run the preview? (It's been years since I used a GUI builder, getting rusty!)

Comment: Stupid question - have you checked the IntelliJ logs?  They're in $HOME/.IntelliJIDEAx/system/log (where x is the version of IJ you're using).

Comment: Definitely not a stupid question. I'm a noob, so had no idea to look there. They're a bit of a mess but yes indeed I can see exactly the errors that are happening at design-time. I would have thought these would just turn up in a console window or something similar. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95443/discussion-between-steve-chaloner-and-xtempore).